# PyCharm Django Javascript Debugger

Tags: javascript, django, pycharm

I cannot figure out how to debug JavaScript code that is executed while loading a Django template.

I have installed the ChromeExtension (localhost and port 63342). Then I have created a RunConfiguration:

JsDebug with the url "http://localhost:63342/ThingShare/2/" Every time I try to debug this I receive :404 not found. The Debugger Console says : "Connected to JetBrains Chrome Extension"

The same url

"http://localhost:8000/ThingShare/2/" works like a charm. I have no clue where to continue here

Comment: The port is different: by default JetBrains embedded web-server works on **63342** port. You're saying that url with port *8000* is working. Are you sure you have executed Debug session of your html file from PyCharm? Looks like you have some third-party web-server running.

Comment: I am using the Django Built in server on port 8000 when I mean "is working". I cannot run the html-file as this template is served by an method view. Somehow I am a little bit confused about this 63352 stuff. Which server has to be started in what mode using which port ?? Question after Question ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this thing to work properly. I switched to the chrome javascript debugger without any hassle

Answer (score 2):

## Pycharm Pro version(prerequisite)

1. `run -> Edit Configurations`
2. 

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Works for me on Windows but not Mac (2021 M1 model) for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd leave this answer for anyone still looking to get Pycharm's Javascript breakpoints working.

After trying to get this working myself I found that if I check the "Run browser" box and also check the "Start Javascript debugger automatically when debugging" box then my Javascript breakpoints worked. Please see the attached image for configuration details.

Note that for this to work Pycharm opens a new browser window. You can only use this new window for debugging as it seems Pycharm makes a connection to that window specifically.

Hope this helps!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you press `ctrl+shift (cmd+shift)` when you click on the **'Starting development server'** link, Pycharm will launch a debug browser window that will respond to breakpoints in your js code.